# Deploying OpenEMR on CloudFoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I setup cloudfoundry in my lab environment. I am trying to deploy openEMR (http://www.open-emr.org/) on it.

This application need some write permissions on files and folders. Application pushed successfully and running, but I don't know how to grant the write permissions on these files and folders. because of the permission, I stuck on installation and application did not installed.

Please tell me how I can grant write permission for the required folders and files.

Thanks
Rana Faisal Munir

Answer (score 0):

The filesystem on Cloud Foundry is ephemeral, if you restart the application, anything written to the filesystem would be lost. I would look at other ways of persisting the data within the application.